# jQuery get attribute on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below style of list items.

```
<li onclick="set_item('BRISBANE')" data-lat="-27.46758" data-lng="153.027892">
    BRISBANE QLD 4000
</li>
```

When the item is clicked its getting the information but how can I get the other 2 items in other 2 textboxes?

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="country_id" onkeyup="autocomplet()">
<input type="text" id="latitude">
<input type="text" id="longitude">
```

JavaScript

```
function set_item(item) {
    $('#country_id').val(item);
    $('#country_list_id').hide();
    var $this = $(this),
        lng = $this.data('lng'),
        lat = $this.data('lat');
    $('#latitude').val(lat); 
    $('#longitude').val(lng);
    alert($this.data('lng'));
}
```

I tried to use the above JS to use `$this.data('lng')` but not sure why its not working.

Comment: try `$(this).attr('data-lng')`

Comment: `alert($(this).data('lng'));` this just prints undefined.

Comment: I made an edit try that @lock

Comment: `this` is the window, it's not what you think it is

Comment: @charlietfl - What should I use to make it working?

Comment: either pass `this` into function as argument in html and `$(arg).data()` or switch and use jQuery handler instead. Very simple to prove my point ..in your function `console.log(this)`

Comment: @salniro - Nope, I tried attr before and came to know that in this scenario data('value') should be used. however, attr didn't help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `this` as an argument to the function:

```js
function set_item(item, li) {
  $('#country_id').val(item);
  $('#country_list_id').hide();
  var $this = $(li),
    lng = $this.data('lng'),
    lat = $this.data('lat');
  $('#latitude').val(lat);
  $('#longitude').val(lng);
  alert($this.data('lng'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li onclick="set_item('BRISBANE', this)" data-lat="-27.46758" data-lng="153.027892">BRISBANE QLD 4000</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="country_id">
<input type="text" id="latitude">
<input type="text" id="longitude">
```

Also, you don't really need to pass the string `BRISBANE` as an argument. `set_item` can use `$this.text()` to get the text of the `LI`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the best idea to bind a click event to list elements, then you can easily identify clicked `li`. In your case `$(this)` was the `$(window)` object.

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li data-item="BRISBANE" data-lat="-27.46758" data-lng="153.027892">BRISBANE QLD 4000</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="country_id">
<input type="text" id="latitude">
<input type="text" id="longitude">
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#list li").click(function(e){
    // $(this) is your li element

    $('#country_id').val($(this).data("item"));
    $('#country_list_id').hide();

    var lng = $(this).data('lng'),
        lat = $(this).data('lat');
    $('#latitude').val(lat); 
    $('#longitude').val(lng);

    alert($(this).data('lng'));
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/